# ¿Cómo ejecutar un query en diferentes schemas en Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Necesto saber si existe un usurio en todos los schemasde mi base de datos en Postgres, osea ejecutar este query

```
SELECT * FROM st_user WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER('usuario');
```

en cada uno de los schemas.

Comment: El simple hecho que necesites hacer esto probablemente indica de que no deberías tener la misma tabla repetida en varios schemas.

Comment: Cada schema contiene la tabal st_user, pero se diferencia por su prefijo: "schema1"."st_user, "schema2"."st_user"... "schemaN"."st_user. Necesito hacer la consulta a cada tabla para verificar si existe dicho usurio.

Comment: @sstan puede que sea una especie de aplicación multitenant en donde cada schema sea un tenant distinto.

Comment: @amenadiel: Espero que así sea. Pero por lo que pide, no me convence. Si hay una necesidad aplicativa de buscar a través todos los schemas para la misma cosa, me parece que el diseño pierde su valor.

Comment: @sstan a mí tampoco me parece muy católico el diseño, pero suena como una especie de multitenant rudimentario.

Comment: @amenadiel asi es, se trata de una aplicación multitenant y quiero validar en que schema existe el usuario.

Comment: Bueno mi respuesta hace más o menos lo que necesitas. Te va a funcionar ejecutándola por ejemplo desde pgAdmin. Dudo que te funcione si intentas ejecutarla desde PHP. Te recomiendo hacer una función para esta tarea

Answer (score 2):

Para esto debieras crear una función PERO sí es posible hacerlo con una tabla temporal y un bloque anónimo [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-do.html).

(voy a suponer que no quieres buscar en los schemas `pg_catalog`, `public` ni `information_schema`. Ahí ve tú cómo filtras qué schemas quieres)

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    r record;
    conteo int;
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tabla_ejemplo (esquema text, registros int);
FOR r IN SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata 
         WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('pg_catalog','public','information_schema')
LOOP
  EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %s.st_user WHERE LOWER(username)=LOWER($1)',r.schema_name) USING 'usuario' INTO conteo;
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tabla_ejemplo (esquema, registros) values ($1,$2)' USING r.schema_name,conteo;
END LOOP;
END$$;
SELECT * FROM tabla_ejemplo;
```

con eso creas una tabla temporal que almacena el nombre del schema y la cantidad de usuarios que calzan con "usuario"